# java.util.Random zero argument enquiry

Tags: java

I am trying to code a game following instructions contained in an OU TMA document which read:

In the constructor, write code to assign a new instance of Random to ran which you should create using the Random class's zero argument constructor

Will this code work?

```
Random ran = new Random(0) ;
```

I am a relative newbie to Java, and I don't understand exactly what the instructions mean

Comment: FWIW, what *your* code does is create a new 'Random' object with a *seed* of 0. Seeding is an important property of a random number generator; it means you can get the same random numbers each time (when you start from the same seed).

Comment: I guess this is a reminder to us all that "no argument" or "no-args" is better (i.e. less ambiguous) terminology than "zero argument".

Answer (score 6):

No, that wont work. A zero-argument constructor is a constructor that takes **no** arguments:

```
Random ran = new Random();
```

is the way to go.

The difference of the two constructors is well described in the API docs:

> **`Random()`**
> Creates a new random number generator. This constructor sets the seed of the random number generator to a value very likely to be distinct from any other invocation of this constructor. 
>      **`Random(long seed)`**
> Creates a new random number generator using a single long seed: `public Random(long seed) { setSeed(seed); }`

That is, a Random object created with an argument, will return the same sequence of random numbers each run of the program, while an object created through the zero-argument  constructor (or, "no argument constructor") will do its best to return different sequences.